# What's going wrong when I try to create a review comment through Github's v3 API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to create a review commit through Github's v3 API and am not succeeding. Consider [this repository](https://github.com/blt/experiment-repo/). There's a single [pull request](https://github.com/blt/experiment-repo/pull/1) and for the purposes of this question let's say I want to leave a 'changes requested' review on that PR. Here's the code I've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
import json

TOKEN='YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'

REPO = "blt/experiment-repo"
PR_NUM = 1
COMMIT_SHA_1 = "4160bee478c3c985eaaa35f161cc922fe20b354a"
COMMIT_SHA_2 = "df9d13a2e35f9b6c228e1f30ea30585ed85af26a"

def main():
    pr_comment_headers = {
        'user-agent': 'benedikt/0.0.1',
        'Authorization': 'token %s' % TOKEN,
        # Accept header per
        # https://developer.github.com/changes/2016-12-16-review-requests-api/
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.black-cat-preview+json',
    }

    msg = "BLEEP BLOOP I AM A ROBOT"
    payload = { 'commit_id': COMMIT_SHA_2,
                'body': msg,
                'event': "REQUEST_CHANGES" }

    # Per https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#create-a-pull-request-review
    review_url = "https://api.github.com/repos/%s/pulls/%s/reviews" % (REPO, PR_NUM)
    res = requests.post(review_url, headers = pr_comment_headers,
            json = json.dumps(payload))
    print(res)
    print(res.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've marked in code comments where I've discovered the API endpoints to hit and with what payloads. Excepting, I must have goofed somewhere because when I run the above program I receive:

```
<Response [422]>
{"message":"Validation Failed","errors":["Variable commitOID of type GitObjectID was provided invalid value","Variable event of type PullRequestReviewEvent was provided invalid value"],"documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#create-a-pull-request-review"}
```

I've verified that the commit SHAs are the exact ones that Github shows and `REQUEST_CHANGES` is the string in the documentation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to let requests encode the request body instead of encoding it yourself with `json.dumps()`, something like this: `requests.post(..., json=payload)`